# How to compute a 'pair confusion matrix'?

Tags: classification, python, clustering, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I don't really understand how the *pair confusion matrix* (used for example in comparing of clusterings) is calculated...

```py
pair_confusion_matrix([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]) 
>>> array([[8, 0], 
[0, 4]])
```

Going by the definition here [link 1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#pair-confusion-matrix) and here [link 2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cluster.pair_confusion_matrix.html)
the upper left entry of the returned 2 by 2 matrix is the number of true negatives, and the lower right entry is the number of true positives.

Where:
TP true positives = number of pairs of samples that are clustered together, and
TN true negatives = number of pairs with both clusterings having the samples not clustered together

But if I were to count here, there are only 2 pairs of samples that are clustered together and only 4 pairs of samples not clustered together.

- **TP**: 0 and 0 + 1 and 1
- **TN**: 4 combinations of 0 and 1 (i.e. 1st 0 with 1st 1, 1st 0 with 2nd 1, 2nd 0 with 1st 1, 2nd 0 with 2nd 1)

---

**edit** 25.10.2021

Going again by the example of two partitions / classifications U and V, where U = [0, 0, 1, 1] and V = [1, 1, 0, 0] for N = 4 objects which I denote as n1, n2, n3 and n4 below.

Based on ttnphns's answer:

If a pair is found in one group in U and is found

- in one group in V => goes to a
- not in one group in V => goes to b

If a pair is found not in one group in U and is found

- in one group in V => goes to c
- not in one group in V => goes to d

then we have pairs ...
(n1, n2) together in U, and also together in V
(n3, n4) together in U, and also together in V
=> a = 2

(n1,n3) not together in U, and also not together in V
(n1,n4) not together in U, and also not together in V
(n2,n3) not together in U, and also not together in V
(n2,n4) not together in U, and also not together in V
=> d = 4

=> b and c both = 0

so the matrix would look like
[[2, 0],
[0, 4]]
with sum of all entries = 6 = 4C2 (4 choose 2) = N(N-1)/2

But the **problem** is, that for this exact example the sklearn documentation for their [pair_confusion_matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cluster.pair_confusion_matrix.html) returns a pair confusion matrix of
[[8, 0],
[0, 4]]
which doesn't makes sense for me at all. Even the sum of all entries is not equal to N(N-1)/2 anymore. The sum 12 which is 24/2 does't even correspond to any nCr value possible since there's no N(N-1) = 24.

Comment: 2x2 Pair confusion matrix' cells are not labelled/understood as "TP, TN, FP, FN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably studying approaches and measures to compare partitions. In particularly, clustering partitions. One of the approaches and a class of measures is based on the so called *comembership (aka pairs) confusion matrix*.

You can find formulas of many similarity measures based on such matrix and used to compare cluster solutions in my document "Compare partitions" on my web-page (the link is on my profile) and the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/586471/3277) based on it.

Here is a screenshot from the document, explaining what is comembership confusion matrix.

[image]

And below is (easy to understand) SPSS code+example to produce comembership confusion matrix for a pair of alternative partitions of a set of objects.

```
matrix.
*Two partitions of the same objects, two categorical vectors of the same lenght n.
*P1 contains some 4 clusters and P2 - some 3 clusters.
*Because the partitions are clusters (not classifications),
*labels (codes) are arbitrary and does not have to use same numbers in P1 and P2.
compute p1= {2;1;1;3;1;3;2;2;1;1;3;3;4}.
compute p2= {1;3;3;3;2;1;2;2;1;1;2;2;2}.
print {p1,p2} /clab= 'P1' 'P2'.
-> P1 P2 
  2  1 
  1  3 
  1  3 
  3  3 
  1  2 
  3  1 
  2  2 
  2  2 
  1  1 
  1  1 
  3  2 
  3  2 
  4  2 
compute n= nrow(p1).
print n.
-> N 
  13

*Turn p1 into n x n binary matrix flagging which objects are in comembership in p1.
compute p1= p1*make(1,n,1).
print p1.
-> P1 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
compute p1= (p1=t(p1)).
print p1.
-> P1 
  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0 
  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0 
  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 
  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0 
  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0 
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1

*Analogously in p2.
compute p2= p2*make(1,n,1).
print p2.
-> P2 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 
  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
compute p2= (p2=t(p2)).
print p2.
-> P2 
  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1

*"Negations" of the comembership matrices.
compute np1= not p1.
compute np2= not p2.
print np1.
print np2.
-> NP1 
  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1 
  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1 
  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1 
  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1 
  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1 
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0 
 -> NP2 
  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  1 
  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 
  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0

*Fill in the 2 x 2 comembership confusion matrix.
compute ccm= make(2,2,0).
compute ccm(1,1)= msum(p1 and p2)-n. /*msum(p1 and p2) means: sum in matrix of (p1=1 AND p2=1)
compute ccm(1,2)= msum(p1 and np2).
compute ccm(2,1)= msum(p2 and np1).
compute ccm(2,2)= msum(np1 and np2).
compute ccm= ccm/2. /*Divide by 2: since comembership matrices were symmetric,
     /*each pair has counted twice
print msum(ccm). /*sum = n*(n-1)/2
-> MSUM(CCM) 
  78
print ccm. /*Ready Comembership confusion matrix
-> CCM 
   4  15 
  20  39
end matrix.

*(This code can be rewritten in a little bit more efficient way).
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you very much for your reply. Your explanation on how to calculate the comembership (pair) confusion matrix with two partitions U and V is very clear. Sadly I am not very proficient in SPSS code, so I wanted to ask a simpler question regarding the screenshot from your document. I have updated an edit in the main question for that. I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: @yliu, What result does sklearn return for the P1, P2 partitions of my example?

Comment: Hi, it returns the matrix: [[78, 40], [30,  8]])

Comment: So, you see yourself that sklear returns it just reordered: {d,c;b,a}, and multiplied by 2 (find the "divide by 2" remark in my example). Thus, everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Per [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#pair-confusion-matrix) I understand it this way.
Let say there are 2 label clusterings: true and pred

```
label_true = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1]
label_pred = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

If we run it with `pair_confusion_matrix(label_true, label_pred)` from sklearn we will get

```
array([[20,  2],
       [ 4,  4]])
```

So how do we get this matrix?
There are 6 objects to be clustered. We can show it like this

```
                    1obj.  2obj.  3obj.  4obj.  5obj.  6obj.
true clustering => [0,     0,     1,     1,     2,     1]
prediction      => [0,     0,     1,     2,     1,     2]
```

**The left upper corner in the confusion matrix is C_00**:
From sklearn doc. it is

> number of pairs with both clusterings having the samples **NOT** clustered
> together

We have to count every possible pair not clustered together in '`true clustering`' and in '`prediction`'. If this pair is not clustered together in both, we will add +2 to C_00. Why 2 rather than 1? I think it is because the permutation matters here.

For example: 1obj. and 3obj. are not in the same cluster in the '`true clustering`' and '`prediction`'. So +2. But when we check 3obj. and 5obj - not suitable because they are in the same cluster in `prediction`.

All pairs for C_00: 1obj.3obj.;1obj.4obj.;1obj.5obj.;1obj.6obj.;2obj.3obj.;2obj.4obj.;2obj.5obj.;2obj.6obj.;4obj.5obj.;5obj.6obj.

**The right bottom corner in the confusion matrix is C_11**:

> number of pairs with both clusterings having the samples clustered
> together

Both `true clustering` and `prediction` have to have elements in the same clusters. Clusters between clusterings may be different. But objects must be in the same clusters within one clustering.

For example: 4obj.6obj. is a candidate to add +2 in the matrix. These are in cluster 1 within `true clustering` and in cluster 2 within `prediction`.

All pairs for C_11: 1obj.2obj.;4obj.6obj.;

**The left bottom corner in the confusion matrix is C_10**:

> number of pairs with the true label clustering having the samples
> clustered together but the other clustering not having the samples
> clustered together

We will count pairs with objects from one cluster in `true clustering` but these objects have to be from different clusters in `prediction`

For example: 3obj.4obj. is from within one cluster in `true clustering` but not in `prediction`

All pairs for C_10: 3obj.4obj.; 3obj.6obj.

**The left bottom corner in the confusion matrix is C_01**:

> number of pairs with the true label clustering not having the samples
> clustered together but the other clustering having the samples
> clustered together

We will count pairs with objects from different clusters in `true clustering` but these objects have to be from one cluster in `prediction`

For example: 3obj.5obj. is from within one cluster in `prediction` but not in `true clustering`

All pairs for C_01: 3obj.5obj.;

The matrix from the first post can be calculated with the same algorithm.

I hope it helps