# How to determine agreement between clustering methods?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, agreement-statistics

Let's say you want to compare the outcome of KMeans and KMedoids. How to determine if cluster 1 from KMeans can be compared with cluster 1 with KMedoids. Or, in other words, let's say KMeans labels the clusters as {0, 1, 2, 3} and KMedoids as {a, b, c, d}: how does one make the correct comparisons? In high dimensions, one cannot visually address which clusters overlap.

Kind regards,
Sean

Comment: This is not easy, there is no guarantee that they will find similar clusters, the clusters could be completely different and not comparable.

Comment: Hmm, the same holds for addressing stability. Is cluster 1 from run 1 from KMeans comparible to cluster 1 from run 2 from KMeans?

Comment: Go please to my web-page and download "Compare partitions". Pay attention to !KO_CLUAGREE and !KO_GRMATCH  macros - their descriptions. The topic concerned in your question is "external cluster validation".

Comment: @ttnphns Great! Thanks! I'll have to dive into the documentation. But does this compare outcomes such that the specific label becomes irrelevant? As basically, label 1 cluster outcome 1 =/ label 1 cluster outcome 2

Comment: @ttnphns Is there a Python equivalent of these macros?

Comment: There is no meaningful 'cluster 1-ness'.  What gets called 'cluster 1' in one output could be called 'cluster 2' in another output. I illustrate comparing clusterings from different methods in my answer to [How to use both binary and continuous variables together in clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/130974/7290)  See also: [How to select a clustering method? How to validate a cluster solution (to warrant the method choice)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/195456/)

Comment: I don't know but I believe there sure must be packages in Python and R which compute statistics comparing cluster solutions without need to know cluster labels, - similar to !KO_cluagree.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be found in the following explanation:

[image: Solution]

Does one know whether a Python implementation of above recursion exists?

It would look something in line with:

```
grouped_together = pd.DataFrame()

for (i in 1:N){
  for (j in (i+1):(N-1)){
    for (k in 1:2){
      grouped_together[i,j,k]=A[i,k]==A[j,k]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can find a good recipe to compute the comembership confusion matrix here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/548778/3277